# Node.js Websocket to Connect Peers on Different Networks

Tags: node.js, websocket, blockchain, p2p, cryptocurrency

In the field of blockchain programming we need to create a network of peers connected using websocket in Node.js.
A lot of presentations are using websockets on the same machine to make connection between two peers like (ws://localhost:8080) and (ws://localhost:8081).
If you want to implement it on two different machenes you need to change localhost to your local IP like (ws://192.168.10.1:8080) and (ws://192.168.10.2:8081), but they have to share the same wifi network.
Now I wonder if the above is the only thing we can do with websocket.
What if I need to connect two peers, one in US and other in UK using websocket. Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, you can have all sorts of arrangements with web sockets, they're just TCP connections to sum. You could have UserA on Server1 and UserB on Server2 and with additional signalling have Server1 tell Server2 messages and vice-versa. Bi-directional communication.

Comment: Something to consider is the state of your app. Something as simple like a users list could fall out of sync on one server versus the other if expectation was to have multiple servers gang up and host many users. With these scenarios we run brokers/message queues/pubsubs but overall these are costly and don't make your app stateless at all making each server reliant on another server. In other words your app slows right down with the added traffic of combined servers.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know nothing about blockchain, but as I understand how it seems to work, you'll likely to encounter the same problems than WebRTC and P2P : you need to discover the public IP address of your peers and even do some NAT traversal on restricted networks when it happen. It's not needed when you use Websockets in browsers, because they don't allow for P2P in this context : they just both connect to a server that is made to be accessible on internet, and the server will allow them to exchange messages.

You can use Websocket protocol to do P2P, but not in a browser.

To do what you want to do (P2P with TCP), you'll need one or more servers, somewhere, at some point, at least to offer to your peers a way to discover their public IPs (something like STUN for webrtc) and to do some signaling to **exchange their IP adresses** to try a direct connection between them when they are not in the same network.

If it's not possible because one (or several) of your peers are hidden behind a restrictive NAT, you'll need to have at least one server out of that NAT, that is reachable by your peers and that will be able to relay the communication between your peers (often it's done via a common open ports like 443).

And I wanted to address this just for clarity sakes :

> In the field of blockchain programming we need to create a network of peers connected using websocket in Node.js

The blockchain is tech agnostic : it doesn't require node.js neither websockets to work. You CAN use Websockets and NodeJS, but you don't need to. What techs you'll have to use heavily depends of what you want to build and/or to use.